# Netbeans always compiling from the beginning

Tags: c++, netbeans, netbeans-7

I'm having a quite big C++ project in Netbeans. It takes about 3 minutes for it to compile (with `-j5` mode enabled).

I'm using my VM server (FreeBSD) hosted on Windows 8 and using SFTP option to compile.

Everything is working like a charm except that it looks like Netbeans is always making clean while compiling (no clean messages appearing in the output console though!). It's really annoying for me to wait 3 minutes for each change I have to make in my source code.

My friend had a similar issue some time ago - it was related to the Netbeans timestamps files (different time setting on the local & remote VM machine). In my case the VM machine time setting is the same as on my PC.

I am currently running Netbeans version 7.3.1 (because later & latest version are having some odd SFTP issue not working correctly). I've also tried the latest beta build including earlier versions and it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Whats the problem? I will appreciate every solution.

Comment: Any chance you can upload/link to a small example of this behavior? My previous uses of Netbeans doesn't have this happening.

Comment: @g19fanatic Its as simple as: Making a change to any project file (.cpp/.h), hitting build button (F11) and voilà - instead of compiling the updated files and finishing the job, its compiling from the scratch, just like it would be making the project clean first (but it doesn't, since no message appears in the output window). Build tools I'm using for this project: http://i.imgur.com/1pkAZ4D.png, versions: http://i.imgur.com/3HDK1Dd.png

Comment: Have you tried turning on the Compile on Save feature? It is a java feature but maybe it is also available for c++ and may help you

Comment: @KuramaYoko No, I haven't. What does it do? I'd rather don't want to always compile on save if thats what it does.

Comment: @Lucas, that is exactly what it does. But I am imagining that it will compile only the file that you are saving. Since we ctrl+s all the time, it shouldn't be expensive.

Comment: @KuramaYoko It won't be much useful for me, since I need to build the project, and not a single file - that wouldn't give me anything since it wont update the output application.

Comment: @Lucas I understand that, but I thought maybe with this method, it wouldn't feel the necessity to recompile everything. Just a long shot guess.

Comment: @Lucas - what's the *type* of your project? I mean when you first create a project you have to choose one of eight variants

Comment: @KuramaYoko Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: @HEKTO It's C/C++ application

Comment: @Lucas - you said "VM server". Do you mean you run FreeBSD guest OS on Windows 8 host using VMware Player?

Comment: @HEKTO FreeBSD 9.2. Instead of VMware Player I'm using VirtualBox by Oracle.

Comment: @Lucas - did you try to `ssh` to the remote server and issue `make build` from command line? Does it rebuilds everything even after a local change?

Comment: @HEKTO No. When I build the project from the console, it works as intended. When I do `/usr/local/bin/gmake -f nbproject/Makefile-FreeBSD.mk dist/FreeBSD/GNU-Generic/my_app` on a fresh built project, the output is: `gmake: dist/FreeBSD/GNU-Generic/my_app is up to date.`, and when I made a change into any file, it simply rebuild that file - which is what I want. So yeah, that is Netbeans messing something up.

Comment: Then I think it makes sense to clean the NetBeans cache on the local machine (when the NetBeans is not running). If you run Windows, it should be somewhere in `C:\Documents and Settings\...\var\cache\remote-files`. Did you try that?

Comment: @HEKTO I've just saw that when I simply copy project files from Netbeans to my VM machine, and build the project from the console its again performing a full rebuild. When I edit a file right on my VM, everything is working like a charm. And yeah, I've cleaned cache few times already.

Comment: @HEKTO Except that the cache on my system is located at : `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache`.

Comment: Yeah... My Windows is obsolete. But it might be a different type of cache. The cache for remote development should contain `remote-files` in its name

Comment: Also, the FreeBSD is not a real Linux. Can you switch to a more Linux-like server - Ubuntu, for example? It looks like files metadata are corrupted during transfer

Comment: @HEKTO I can't really move into Linux since my project is using BSD watchers and I don't have enough time/don't want to rewrite into the libevents for example. So I'm kinda 'forced' to use BSD. Currently I am using the following method which works... but it's annoying for large amount of edited files: right click on the latest edited file -> upload to vm@[...] which will upload only a single file and then done the compiling through the console.

Comment: And I don't have access to FreeBSD on my side... The NetBeans team explicitly says that they support Solaris and Linux only for remote development. So, good luck!

Comment: @HEKTO Isn't there an option in Netbeans to upload a file on save? That could help a lot since I wouldn't have to upload anything. There was such possibility for PHP projects.

Comment: Couldnt you make a script for building so you dont let netbeans screw that up

Comment: @gia Yeah, but then I couldn't build directly from Netbeans which would make this IDE kind of useless then...

Comment: It's more of a workaround, but have you tried using ccache? https://ccache.samba.org/

Comment: @ChrisLaplante How can I link ccache to work with Netbeans compilations properly? Something like past-build event would be needed.

Comment: @Lucas: Something like this: https://i.imgur.com/QMEQBxh.png. Just prepend your compiler with `ccache`

Answer (score 0):

There is excellent article "[Make Dependency Checking](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/depchecking.html)" on this topic by NetBeans team which is worth reading to understand this behaviour.

NetBeans internally uses make utility for dependency checking defined in Makefile. When we create a new project in NetBeans, it enables **"Full rebuild"** feature. This leads to this particular behaviour.

However if want to avoid this, we can change this particular feature to **"Incremental rebuild"**.

For complete information and to understand its consequences, please refer the above article from NetBeans team.

Comment: I understand that this behaviour is set in the Makefile. My project is not that large - it has less than 60 project files, so I guess it'd be fine if I could use incremental rebuild. However, there is no clear explanation on how to change the build option for an existing project. How can I do this?

Comment: There is screen shot in the article which contains the all information regarding this which looks  self  explanatory. Apart from this I do not have anything to share on this.

Comment: Everything seems to be correct, however - I have disabled the dependency checking and it's still making a full rebuild. Thats why I'm wondering.